# How to cast a variable to a particular type to convince typescript that everwhere?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-5, custom-errors

For IE reasons I need to build a custom Error, however, as best as I can do it, the error has to be checked with the constructor.

```
customError instanceof CustomError; // false
customError.constructor === CustomError; // true
```

Now how can I convince typescript that in an if statement?

```
if (customError.constructor === CustomError) {
  customError.customMethod1() // typescript complaints
  customError.customMethod2() // typescript complaints
  customError.customMethod3() // typescript complaints
  customError.customMethod4() // typescript complaints
}
```

EDITED:

Background is when you are compiling down to ES5, some inheritances cannot be compatible.

Is there a way I can cast it once and not have to use `as` everytime I use the variable?

So far the only way to work with it is:

```
const myCustomError = (customError as CustomError)
```

Open to other bright ideas.

Comment: You're mixing casting with constructor/instance comparison. Are you trying to cast something or compare something? `instanceof` is what you want for comparison. Casting you can use `{} as T` or `<T>{}`

Comment: @mwilson TypeScript will automatically narrow the type of `customError` inside the conditional statement [when using `instanceof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#instanceof-type-guards). OP is not trying to do a cast, they're asking whether there is a way to get TypeScript to do the same when having to use a `.constructor` comparison

Comment: @mwilson Not when transpiling to ES5.

Comment: Can you share the bit where you create the customError?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write an [User-Defined Type Guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
function isCustomError(x: any): x is CustomError {
    return x.constructor === CustomError;
}
```

And use it:

```
if (isCustomError(err)) {
    err.customMethod1();
}
```

See this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCCuEAuB7AtgUQE5ZV6A3gLABQ00wKAdslvMKlgBQCUhAvqecIqmgLIBTJAAsUAEwCMrDqU4lSAM3hUGAS2rQ1EBMnTZczAB4AuaGCoBPFmaNaYuvgbyEu5aFmHwsVaEYB0lDRIdAwuALyRcLz6OHgA3HKkpCDC0II40OHQVIIA7tDOzGyQ0XqYcfgAPoWViQokGViBMQLCYlKs8dAA9D21hskkaorQTNqOsYZMTSxsxGTuTS3lQqIS0izdfdAA8gDSckA).